# Как разрезать OBJ или FBX модель на части?

Tags: 3d, model

Как разрезать OBJ или FBX модель на части?
У мене есть 3Д модель которою нужно разрезать на части.
Автомобиль который с колесами. Нужно их отрезать и сохранить в отдельном файле. И машину без колес.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Открываете в blender и отрезаете. Автоматически это вряд ли возможно

Answer (score 0):

1. Открыть исходную модель в любом удобном вам редакторе.
2. Выделить ненужные части.
3. Удалить.
4. Сохранить как новую часть.
5. Повторить шаги 1-4 до достижения нужной разбивки.

Comment: очень странный алгоритм, но пусть

Comment: @KoVadim чем же странный? Уточню, что это самый безопасный алгоритм, т.к. вырезание частей и их вставка в новую пустую модель чревато расстыковками (геометрии, материалов, доп.каналов, итп итд).

Comment: да и удаление кусков тоже самое. Хотя, если редактор не может перенести все дополнительное... то грош цена такому редактору